# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS: FN-Brightness Key Stopped Working

Tags: 14.04, intel-graphics, brightness, acer

Hello dear Ubuntu Community,

After i installed some Ubuntu Updates on my PC,my FN-Key stopped working. (But i can still change it in the System settings.
I tried many ways to fix it trough the `/etc/default/grub` file.

My actual entry is:

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=
>   acpi_backlight=vendor" GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

I have a `Acer Aspire E1-510` with `Intel Inside PENTIUM`

Please Help me :/

[PS: Sorry for my bad English i'm German]

Comment: ON my acer asus 1005PE, I need `acpi_osi=Linux` to have it working.

Comment: Added as an answer, please accept it!

Answer (score 4):

Please try:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux"
```

It works at least for me on my acer asus 1005P, contrary to what it's written [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ASUS_Eee_PC_1005P). (maybe the kernels are different).

Answer (score -3):

I fixed it with this entry in `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux" 
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Thanks to Rmano