# Screen brightness control not working: Lenovo g50-45: AMD Radeon: Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: lenovo, screen, brightness, radeon, amd-graphics

I've a Lenovo G50-45 machine with AMD processor [Radeon APU A4-6000 with R2 Graphics]. I tried the [solution from Rmano](https://askubuntu.com/a/552526/32239) but no success. Using Ubuntu 14.04.

I tried the solution posted here: [Ubuntu 14.04 LTS: FN-Brightness Key Stopped Working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/552507/ubuntu-14-04-lts-fn-brightness-key-stopped-working), but no success.

Any idea about the issue? Any other workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Got this issue resolved. Installed the driver "linux-amd-catalyst-14.6-beta-v1.0-jul11" provided by AMD.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this in-distro now which is the better way to support it over time.

> `sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-amdcccle fglrx-core`

Comment: I already have had this tested deanx. Doesn't work for me. For 14.04 it seems to be an issue with fglrx. However, it seems with Ubuntu 15 the graphics driver comes in pre-installed and has no issue.