# Compatibility with Asus Zenbook UX501 series in Ubuntu

Tags: laptop, asus, compatibility

I was looking for a powerful Notebook and found the Asus Zenbook UX501JW-FI177H. I've done some research about problems with Ubuntu, but could not find anything for this model.
Does anyone have experience with Ubuntu on this model?

Comment: The validity of answers to questions about hardware compatibility is usually very short, and as such this is not a good question for this site.

Comment: I installed Ubuntu on my UX501JW. Airplane mode and `Fn+F5`/`Fn+F6` keys to control brightness were not working. I solved the issue with [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/552507/ubuntu-14-04-lts-fn-brightness-key-stopped-working) and [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1460088) ( `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="` ). I installed the drivers with [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/658040/ubuntu-14-04-nvidia-drivers-for-geforce-gtx-960m). The Wifi doesn't work after suspending, everything else is working properly. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Touchscreen & WebCam is not working as good as in MS Windows, otherwise it's quite good.
Even, I am writing this response from my zenbook pro-ux501JW :)

Comment: Great, thanks man (: the version I'm gonna buy doesn't  have a touchscreen, but still, good to know that I don't have to worry about it too much. 
What about the power management? And battery life? Is it like really bad or good?

Comment: @L1nuxUs3r Could you please re-write the description in your question otherwise it is sounding more like a shopping or hardware recommendation and  coming under clauses mentioned at http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: which version of Ubuntu have you tested?