# Ubuntu 14.04: nvidia drivers for GeForce GTX 960M

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, gpu, gpu-driver

I have **Ubuntu 14.04** installed on an [Asus N551JW](https://www.asus.com/Notebooks/N551JW/specifications/) laptop with these two graphic cards:

- Integrated Intel® HD Graphics 4600
- **NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX 960M** 4G GDDR5

By default, Ubuntu recognizes the Intel graphic card but not the NVIDIA one.

When I try to install the Nvidia's drivers I get one of the following errors (depending on how I install drivers):

- **Ubuntu freeze in the initial loading screen** (before showing the login screen): I get this error if I install drivers from the user interface, going to "Software and Updates" > "Additional Drivers" then selecting the Nvidia drivers (instead of the Nouveau).
- I get a **black screen instead of the login screen** (I can hear the login alert sound): I get this error using the commands listed below.

So, **how to install Nvidia's drivers for my laptop?**

---

#### What I already tried

I tried as explained here:

[How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers)

[Correct nvidia+intel graphics setup in 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/472928/correct-nvidiaintel-graphics-setup-in-14-04)

these things:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus linux-headers-generic

sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
sudo nvidia-xconfig
```

But I get the errors described above.

Comment: Did you also try the [official ones](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/83686/en-us)?

Comment: @Matthieu I think that if you go to "Software Updates" > "Additional Drivers" and select to install Nvidia drivers these are the official ones (the same you linked). Also Pilot6's answer should make you install official Nvidia drivers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You did all wrong (almost). Run

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get purge bumblebee* primus
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:bumblebee/stable
```

and hope that you did not spoil everything completely with previous attempts.

Comment: It is also available `nvidia-355`, could it be better than 352?

Comment: It is a beta driver.

Comment: I added that thx.

Comment: nvidia-352 was deleted from xorg-edgers, don't know why yet.

Comment: Yeah, they removed 3 driver versions from Trusty. I have no clue why.

Comment: I changed the repository @Jim

Comment: That worked, cheers mate.