# bumblebee installation with trusty Ubuntu on Geforce GTX960M on notebook MSIGE722QC Apache

Tags: graphics, xubuntu, hybrid-graphics

I am trying to install Xubuntu14.04 on my MSI GE72QC with NVIDIA GTX960M.
After including nomodeset in the GRUB I install Xubuntu. I clik on download updates with the installation. Reboot does not work so I modify again the grub with nomodeset.
Then I follow [Ubuntu 14.04: nvidia drivers for GeForce GTX 960M](https://askubuntu.com/questions/658040/ubuntu-14-04-nvidia-drivers-for-geforce-gtx-960m) that is I do 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:bumblebee/stable

I would like then to see if the nividia graphic works. The suggestion I received in the installation is type glxspheres.
I type glxspheres and I get :
unknown command.

I guess this means that bumblebee is not installed. But since I loaded prime do I need to install bumblebee? If not how can I check that the nvidiadiver works?
I thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you do not have to install bumblebee - **nvidia-prime** is the **replacement** to switch the GPUs.

Use the NVIDIA X Server Settings application (**Prime Profiles**) to switch between the two GPUs.

In case this does not work, uninstall every NVIDIA related software ... so - boot your computer ...

When the **GRUB boot menu** appears : Highlight the **Ubuntu menu entry** and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add the `nouveau.modeset=0` parameter to the end of the linux line ... Then press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

**Update :** Enter your user name and password - then execute :

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo apt-get purge nvidia* bumblebee  
sudo ppa-purge ppa:bumblebee/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo reboot
```

Now install the latest available official stable NVIDIA drivers 358.16 from the short-lived branch.

When the **GRUB boot menu** appears : Highlight the **Ubuntu menu entry** and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add the `nouveau.modeset=0` parameter to the end of the linux line ... Then press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

**Update :** Enter your user name and password - then execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-358 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Thank you this helps. I do not understand the last sentence. I  Should do this before installing what???

Comment: hello I did the procedure a first time. I gos a system error and then I restarted the installation from scratch. at the installation of the nvidia-358, i got the following error message : cannot find nvidia-358. I then used nvidia-352 instead. when rebooting after purgin xorg repository I had a system error regarding Xorg. This error was filed.

Comment: Then I did sudo aptitude safe upgrade. The result is not too good : in primeprofiles, I cannot choose to use the intel graphic card. it is not possible to modify . Aslo it is not possible do put the computer so sleep or hibernation.

Comment: To make it easier for you to understand I changed the order of instructions and updated the answer. Important : You do not have to purge xorg ! In the original answer I said that you should purge the xorg-edgers PPA (in case you added it before). Now I implemented the purge command for the bumblebee PPA ... and again : you only have to purge the PPA in case you added it before and did not already remove it. :)

Comment: I re installed every thing from scratch and applied your sugestions in the right order. The nvidia-358 is founded but the installation does not terminate properly : during the update intramfs I get an error message regarding "not syncing" and a panick kernel. I then rebooted and it is not possible because the efiboot file is corrupted!...

Comment: @piscvau : After your last comment I think the best and most easiest way to solve these various issues would be to make a clean install of Ubuntu - there seems to be messed up too much. The corrupted boot file has nothing to do with the graphics drivers. Because you have quite new hardware I recommend to install Ubuntu 15.10 which comes with kernel 4.2 and afterwards install the NVIDIA drivers following the second part of the instructions. There is nothing to remove, so part 1 can be skipped. Save your personal data to another disk before and restore it back after the installation is finished.

Comment: Well, Thank you so much. I did yesterday so several clean install of xubuntu from scatch and it never worked. Yesterday I got another PC and irt worked fine. So I suspect there was a Hardware problem on the other machine. Anyhow thank you so much. I translated your input to a french forum.